# Insert duplicates values linq

Tags: c#, linq

In a collection of values

```
[0, 2, 25, 30]
```

I'm trying to do with linq

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30] //Replicate 2 times (values repeated 3 times)
```

Is there someway to do it with linq?

Comment: Nobody asked... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Based on the smae question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678403/repeat-values-for-n-times) it seems like you have posted here your homework without even tried something. To improve your skill on software programming, I recommend you to try, search before asking solution.

Comment: @SeM: i guess no one wanted to feed the [“What have you tried” epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understand that point, it's annoying to see same question over and over again, but I guess main reason for that question was to make OP to try something before posting, to make him think about his problem, research and I personally think, that it will be more useful for him than the direct answer. But, to avoid that "epidemic", I will probably not use that question anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With value types it's easy, just use `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
var result = collection.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 3));
```

If it was an array use `ToArray` if it was a list use `ToList` at the end.

With reference types it depends if you really want the same reference, then you can also use `Repeat`. Otherwise you need to create "deep-clones" of the instance, for example by using a [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) if available:

```
var result = collection
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new YourType(x)));
```

Comment: If you want to keep the yeilding feature of `IEnumerable` i suggest you look for [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) project on git hub, it has a `Repeat` method that does exactly that but keeps the yeilding. Lots of good contributor on this project

Answer (score 2):

Of course Tim's answer does answer this question. But posting this as an alternative answer (if you have to repeat for fewer times)

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> newList = list.SelectMany(x => new List<int>(3) { x, x, x }).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer have a problem in it, what if you don't know how many times you want to repeat items, for example you will leave it to user input?

Comment: @SeM yeah, this answer is too much limited. and that I have mentioned in answer too.  However in question OP was clear with the fact that how many time he want to repeat. motive of posting this answer to make reader aware about something like this can be done too.