# Repeat values for n times

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a collection of values

```
[1, 4, 23, 90]
```

and these values should be stored into a array repeated `3` times *without using* **Linq**

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 23, 23, 23, 90, 90, 90]
```

what I've tried so far

```
int[] collection = { 1, 4, 23, 90 };
int multiplier = 3;
int[] result = new int[collection.Length * multiplier];
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < multiplier; j++)
        result[i + j] = collection[i];
```

but somehow only the first `6` fields of the array are filled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678021/insert-duplicates-values-linq

Comment: At least this OP have tried something which is not the case for the duplicated question ;-)

Comment: Why duplicate? maybe OP don't want solution with LINQ?

Comment: @SeM look at the values, it's the same homework...

Comment: @Freggar I saw, I was just commented on "duplicate" post and immediately after that I saw this one.

Comment: Makes you wonder if the tutor keeps an eye on StackOverflow... I know I would, if I was a tutor. :)

Comment: If you don't want to just copy an answer. The problem in your code is in this line `result[i + j] = collection[i];`. Play it through with a few values for i an j and you will find your mistake.

Comment: @Toshi: I've reopened your question, but added the remark that you are not looking for a *Linq* solution

Comment: @Toshi: let's highlight the request (no Linq, please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *not* looking for a *Linq* solution,

[Insert duplicates values linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678021/insert-duplicates-values-linq)

then just compute which item to put into `result`: `i`-th `result`'s item corresponds to `i / multiplier` `collection`s one

```
int[] collection = new int[] { 0, 2, 25, 30 };
int multiplier = 3;
int[] result = new int[collection.Length * multiplier];

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
  result[i] = collection[i / multiplier];
```